# If there are $k$ places and we have $m$ different numbers repeated $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_m$ times, then the number of ordered samples is ...

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, proof-writing, multinomial-distribution

I am currently studying the textbook *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger. In a section on combinatorics, the authors state the following:

> In general, if there are $k$ places and we have $m$ different numbers repeated $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_m$ times, then the number of ordered samples is $\dfrac{k!}{k_1 ! k_2 ! \dots k_m !}$. This type of counting is related to the *multinomial distribution*, which we will see in Section 4.6.

I've been looking for a proof of this, but I've been unable to find any. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to either provide a proof or direct me to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to see this result is to first assume that all the numbers are different. There are therefore $k!$ arrangements.

Now suppose we make $k_1$ of the numbers the same. Then the arrangements will occur in blocks each containing $k_1!$ arrangements that we cannot tell apart. So we now have $\frac{k!}{k_1!}$ distinguishable arrangements.

Now repeat this for $k_2, k_3, ...$

We end up with the answer $$\dfrac{k!}{k_1 ! k_2 ! \dots k_m !}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm unsure about the language used by the author. For instance, let's say that we have the 4 numbers $2, 4, 9, 12$. The number of ordered samples (with replacement) is $n^r = 4^4$ (number of possible arrangements of size $r = 4$ from $n = 4$ objects). By the multiplication rule, we can order the sample in $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 24$ ways. Now let's say that want to know the number of ordered samples that would result in the set $\{ 2, 4, 4, 9 \}$. We have two $4$s, so the $24$ that we calculated does some double-counting in this case, so we must correct [...]

Comment: [...] for this. We have $k = 4$ places, and we have $m = 1$ number repeated $k_1 = 1$ time, right? So to correct for this, we divide $24$ by $k_1 = 1!$? But that's not what the textbook does; rather, the textbook divides $24$ by $2!$? So I'm wondering if you could clarify some of the language used in this theorem.

Comment: For your example the number of arrangements is $4!/2!$ because there are two $4$s. (Exactly as given in the answer). Note that the $k_i$ are $2,1,1$ in whatever order you want.

Comment: Hmm, I think the authors phrased the theorem incorrectly: "$m$ different numbers **repeated** $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_m$ times". If a number appears only once, then it is by definition not repeated; a number is only repeated if its appears more than once. Therefore, a number that appears twice (such as $4$ in this case) is **repeated *once***, meaning that, by the phrasing of the theorem by the authors, we have $1!$ in the denominator for the two $4$s, and two $0!$s in the denominator for the other two numbers. See what I mean?

Comment: It is arguably ambiguous but a phrase such as "3 repetitions of ..." is typically taken to mean that there are "3 occurrences"" and not 4.

Comment: hmm, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to arrange the letters AABBBCCCC?

1) Choose $2$ spots from $9$ for the A's   ($9*8/(2*1)$)
2) Choose $3$ spots from $7$ for the B's   ($7*6*5/(3*2*1)$)
3) Choose $4$ spots from $4$ for the C's   ($4*3*2*1/(4*3*2*1)$)
Multiply these three fractions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it isn't clear to me what you're doing here. Additional explanation in your answer would greatly help.

Comment: @ThePointer   $m=3$,$k=9$, the $k_i$'s are $2,3,4$ and we're finding the number of distinct arrangements of those $9$ letters. By multiplication principle the total number is the product of those three binomial coefficients which comes out to $9! / (2! 3! 4!)$ as in the formula you wrote. As for the process, you can break down arranging the $9$ letters into three steps 1) pick $2$ locations out of $9$ available spots for the A's, 2) Having done that, there are $7$ open spots for the B's -- pick $3$ of them, 3) Having done that, there are $4$ .... etc. Does that help?

Comment: what binomial coefficients?

Comment: $(9*8) / (2*1)$ is a binomial coefficient, namely C($9,2$): it comes out to $36$ and represents the numbers of ways to pick $2$ objects from a set of $9$ distinct objects. Similarly C($7,3$) and C($4,4$) occur in the example I used. Are you familiar with binomial coefficients? The formula you asking about is a straightforward generalization of them — in fact, the case of your formula with $k = 2$ IS EXACTLY the definition of a binomial coefficient.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't even notice that the binomial coefficients were being used in this process; the textbook itself goes through a different process, without ever even mentioning the use of binomial coefficients (see the example I gave in my comments to S. Dolan's answer -- it's from the textbook). I see what you did now. Thanks for the novel example.

Comment: I meant $m = 2$, not $k=2$, in the last sentence of my last comment ... sorry.